# HTML, using a relative URL as a BASE URL?

Tags: html

Is it possible to set a base url on a page with a relative value?

For example, I have two websites (website A and website B). For Website B it will be located at www.website-a.com/website-b. So could I set the BASE href as '/website-b/'?

Thanks

Comment: I think it takes less than 5 minutes to try it yourself...

Comment: ... and less than one minute to google the answer.

Comment: @KennyTM: Indeed, as long as you test it in more than one browser ;-) Although it's hardly worth mentioning (and I do so only as a response to your comment), IE8 in compat mode and IE7 or lower  (incorrectly) support a relative URL for the base element.

Comment: IE9 and IE8 (Compat Mode or not) don't support a relative base. Test page: http://www.enhanceie.com/test/base/relative.html

Comment: For the most upvoted comment *("I think it takes less than 5 minutes to try it yourself...")*, I hope people still sometimes at least "resort to" reading some specs, too, instead of churning out non-portable, brittle code produced by "experimental programming".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, base URL can not be relative. The closest reference I found was RFC 1808: http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1808/13.htm and [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html)

Comment: Okay thanks, I guess I could use a bit of PHP for the domain so I don't need to change anything when moving from dev to live. Thanks.

Comment: @Probocol if you can use PHP for the domain, why not use it directly where you specify the links? `BASE` makes things that much harder to maintain on the long run.

Comment: FWIW: This is from the Google Code archive pages (copied from the main page of the markdown editor ("Pagedown") used right here, on SO): `<base href="/archive/">` *(In fact, this causing problems in my proxy brought me here... So @jholster's offhand "google it" comment got a completely new meaning... Is "self-inflicted infinite recursion" a thing? :) )*

Answer (score 4):

Not possible according to [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/links.html#edef-BASE):

> href = uri [CT]
>   This attribute specifies an absolute URI that acts as the base URI for resolving relative URIs.

Comment: *(Googlers, note the date/URL: that was for HTML4!)*